# Salesforce1 for Android 4.1 or less (using URL)

Tags: salesforce1-app

Wanted a  quick pointer for the above subject
As I understand there is a web based version.
(It's applicable for Android users who are not on 4.3 , which is, btw.  very problematic version.)

I googled it and followed the instructions on item 1
http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/12/things-to-know-about-s1.html

I assembled the following URL
https://eu1.salesforce.com/one/one.app

It yielded 404

Can anyone assist in assembling the right URL in order to access Salesforce1 from older Android version. As I understand there is a working workaround.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the mobile browser app enabled. Setup > Mobile Administration > Salesforce1 > check "Enable the Salesforce1 mobile browser app" > click Save.

Once you've done that, users who log in through login.salesforce.com from Chrome for Android will be automatically directed to the Salesforce1 interface. If you have users on other browsers or Android versions before 4.0 (and thus unable to install Chrome), they'll need to navigate to the URL themselves.